# How to write an "if statement" while the variable within the "if statement" can be any integer within a range between 1 and 1000

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I want to use the "or" command --> ||

I want to write the following pseudo code below in matlab, but without having to write it out all the way to 1000

```
if (n==1 or 2 or 3 or 4 ... or 1000)
 ....
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ismember:

```
if ismember(n, 1:1000)
     % do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [any](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.ht)

```
if(any(n==1:1000))
    % do domething
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you want to use or, but if you use and you could do:

```
if (n >= 1 && n <= 1000 && mod(n,1) == 0)
        %your code here
end
```

and if you want some exclusion just adjust the condition.

Comment: This will be true if n=1.5 for example.

Comment: Not to be picky, but using "{" and "}" is not a correct matlab syntax, i think.